# Size of the ScrollView not changing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview

I have two rows in my grid on the page. The first one displays some info. In the second row I have another grid with two rows. First one is a stackLayout and displays a donut chart, and the second one is a stackLayout with a scrollview and the button. When the button gets clicked the the scroll view gets translated on the y axis to display the history items. However the height of the scrollview is not changing. does anyone know why??

xaml file

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">

        <forms:ChartView x:Name="PieChart" HeightRequest="300"/>

    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout x:Name="HistoryScroll" Grid.Row="1" TranslationY="120">
          <StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="0">
             <Frame x:Name="HistoryBtn" Padding="0" Margin="5, 5, 0, 5" CornerRadius="5" 
                              HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"   
                              BackgroundColor="#000058">
                <Button Text="History" TextColor="#fff" 
                              BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"               
                              VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                              Margin="0" Padding="0" Clicked="HistoryBtnHandler"/>
             </Frame>

             <Frame BackgroundColor="LightGray" BorderColor="Transparent" Padding="0" 
                                     HeightRequest="10" Margin="0" HasShadow="False"/>
          </StackLayout>

          <ScrollView  HeightRequest="300" IsEnabled="True">
              <StackLayout HeightRequest="300">                                    
                   <Label Text="History Item"/>
                   <Label Text="History Item"/>
                   <Label Text="History Item"/>
                   <Label Text="History Item"/>
                   <Label Text="History Item"/>
                   <Label Text="History Item"/>
                   <Label Text="History Item"/>
                   <Label Text="History Item"/>
                   <Label Text="History Item"/>
                   <Label Text="History Item"/>
                   <Label Text="History Item"/>
                   <Label Text="History Item"/>
                   <Label Text="History Item"/>
                   <Label Text="History Item"/>
                   <Label Text="History Item"/>
              </StackLayout>
          </ScrollView>
  </StackLayout>
 </Grid>                    
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the `ScrollView` correctly, Firstly, you should as Prateek's said set the `RowDefinition Height="*"` or set `<RowDefinition Height="auto"/>`.

After that, I found your scrollview cannot be scrolled, if you set the specific height for your `StackLayout` in your `ScrollView`, your `Scrollview` cannot be scrolled. Because your display content's height is equal with your `Scrollview`, left content was coverred.

If I delete the Height of your `StackLayout` in your `ScrollView`, it could be scrolled. but the content is still not display completely. you can see this GIF(I change the last serveral items' name, such as History Item1, History Item2..).

[image]

I must decrease the height of the `ScrollView`, it could be displayed correctly.Here is code.

```
  <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
                <microcharts:ChartView
                   VerticalOptions="Fill"
                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                   WidthRequest="2000"
                   HeightRequest="200"
                   x:Name="mcProgress"
                   Margin="0"
                   IgnorePixelScaling="True"
                    />
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout x:Name="HistoryScroll" Grid.Row="1" TranslationY="120">
                    <StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="0">
                        <Frame x:Name="HistoryBtn" Padding="0" Margin="5, 5, 0, 5" CornerRadius="5" 
                              HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"   
                              BackgroundColor="#000058">
                            <Button 
                              Text="History" TextColor="#fff" 
                              BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"               
                              VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                              Margin="0" Padding="0" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
                        </Frame>

                        <Frame BackgroundColor="LightGray" BorderColor="Transparent" Padding="0" 
                                     HeightRequest="10" Margin="0" HasShadow="False"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <ScrollView HeightRequest="200"   IsEnabled="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
                        <StackLayout >
                            <Label Text="History Item"/>
                            <Label Text="History Item"/>
                            <Label Text="History Item"/>
                            <Label Text="History Item"/>
                            <Label Text="History Item"/>
                            <Label Text="History Item"/>
                            <Label Text="History Item"/>
                            <Label Text="History Item"/>
                            <Label Text="History Item"/>
                            <Label Text="History Item6"/>
                            <Label Text="History Item5"/>
                            <Label Text="History Item4"/>
                            <Label Text="History Item3"/>
                            <Label Text="History Item2"/>
                            <Label Text="History Item1"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ScrollView>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have allocated only 200DP for Grid Row=1 `ScrollView` will only have maximum of 200display pixels. If you need to make it occupy remaining space set the `Height` to `*`

```xml
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```